# Django - Preferred programming design for forms without violating DRY

Tags: html, django, django-forms, django-templates

I have an app that uses a form that a customer will fill out and submit lets call it formA. Now I also have the same form being used by the staff with some additional fields being rendered. In my forms.py I am forced to include those added fields to the form even though I dont want them to be rendered from the customers point of view or else I cant use the same form for the staff.

Currently I have been including logic in the template to ignore these fields that I dont want by using the `{% ifnotequal %}` tag with `field.label` in a for loop iteration over the fields but I feel as it is becoming too cumbersome and confusing to read.

I know another option would have been to create a separate form but then I feel that would violate DRY.

Is there a preferred way of reusing forms in this case or a better way of going about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create different forms for the customer and staff views, and then use inheritance to avoid repetition.

```
class BaseForm(forms.Form):
    field1 = forms.CharField()

class StaffForm(BaseForm):
    staff_field = forms.CharField()

class CustomerForm(BaseForm):
    customer_field = forms.CharField()
```

I would avoid using `{% ifnotequal %}` in the template to decide whether or not to display fields -- logic like this does not belong in the template.

Comment: Ah I didnt even think about using inheritance for some reason. Thank you for the help!